# GUI Builder for jQuery

Tags: jquery, user-interface, toolkit

I've seen apps/tools that initially give one the impression that they include Visual GUI Building tools.  But i never see these things in action .  For example, Jquery UI has their showcase of widgets but not a way to simply drag and from widgets onto a form, and get the outline down quickly.  Same thing for DOJO.  Lots of cools widget but no GUI builder.

Am I missing one of these tools or can someone suggest another?  I see DHTMLX which is really nice and includes a builder.  They're a little pricey.  I am looking for something like that which creates the initial jQuery code containers, placement, etc.

Any good ones out there.

Answer (score 0):

[Wakanda](http://www.wakanda.org/) sounds like what you are looking for.